# How to Generate Two Separate Y-Axes For A Histogram on the Same Figure In Seaborn

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn, histogram, kernel-density

I'd like to generate a single figure that has two y axes: `Count` (from the histogram) and `Density` (from the KDE).

I want to use `sns.displot` in Seaborn `>= v 0.11`.

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# graph 1: This should be the Y-Axis on the left side of the figure
sns.displot(df['total_bill'], kind='hist', bins=10)

# graph 2: This should be the Y-axis on the right side of the figure
sns.displot(df['total_bill'], kind='kde')
```

The code I've written generates two separate graphs; I could just use a facet grid for two separate graphs, but I want to be more concise and place the two y-axes on the two separate grids into a single figure sharing the same x-axis.

[image: seaborn_tips_dataset_dist]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`displot()` is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html), which can create multiple subplots inside a figure.  As such, you don't have control over individual axes.

To create combined plots, you can use the underlying axes-level functions: `histplot()` and `kdeplot()` for Seaborn v.0.11. These functions accept an `ax=` parameter. `twinx()` creates a second y-axis.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.histplot(df['total_bill'], bins=10, ax=ax)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.kdeplot(df['total_bill'], ax=ax2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, the y-axes aren't aligned. The left axis only tells something about the histogram. E.g. the highest bin having height 68 means that there are exactly 68 total bills between `12.618` and `17.392`. The right axis only tells something about the kde. E.g. a y-value of `0.043` for `x=20` would mean there is about 4.3 % probability that the total bill would be between `19.5` and `20.5`.

To align both similar to `sns.histplot(..., kde=True)`, the area of the histogram can be calculated (bin width times number of data values) and used as a scaling factor. Such scaling would make the area of the histogram and the area below the kde curve equal when measured in pixels:

```py
num_bins = 10
bin_width = (df['total_bill'].max() - df['total_bill'].min()) / num_bins
hist_area = len(df) * bin_width
ax2.set_ylim(ymax=ax.get_ylim()[1] / hist_area)
```

[image: scaled kde plot]

Note that the right axis would be more similar to a percentage if the histogram would use a bin width with a power of ten (e.g. `sns.histplot(..., bins=np.arange(0, df['total_bill'].max()+10, 10)`). Which bins would be most suitable strongly depends on how you want to interpret your data.

Comment: Good explanation of the figure-level/axes-level distinction, but if you literally want the KDE curve *on top of* the histogram you should add `kde=True` to the `histplot` (or `displot`) call. True that won't give you both y axes, but they're not actually equivalent here the way the plot implies (the limits are set by matplotlib's autoscaling to the artists, not a mathematical relationship between count/density), and the density axis is not really interpretable anyway.

Comment: Nice elaboration; you state the interpretation of the density value exactly correctly in your edit. Just noting for others that "density" as a y axis value has a very high likelihood of being misinterpreted, so use caution when showing a plot like this.