# Show 2 histograms on the same plot with 1 calculated histogram in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have created the following sample dataset:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id':np.arange(0,1000),
    'sent_click_diff':np.random.randint(400, size=1000),
    'clicked_or_not':np.random.choice( ['clicked','not clicked'], 1000),
    })
```

And here's a sample code to display the % of users on the Y axis:

```
stepsize = 10
x_axis_values = np.arange(1, 400, stepsize)
#create histogram, using percentages instead of counts
plt.hist(sample_df['sent_click_diff'], weights=np.ones(len(sample_df)) / len(sample_df), bins=x_axis_values)

#apply percentage format to y-axis
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.xlim(1,400)
plt.title('Distribution of number of days since last click')
plt.xlabel('Number of days since last click')
plt.ylabel('% users')
plt.show()
```

It gives me the following chart:
[image]

I would like `% clicked` for each bin on a Y2 axis in a different color on the same plot. How can I do that?
In particular, how do I calculate `% clicked` for each bin?

TIA for any help.

Comment: have you already tried using a subplot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400669/how-to-generate-two-separate-y-axes-for-a-histogram-on-the-same-figure-in-seabor check this answer out, it may help

Comment: Just updated the question. What's the best way to calculate `% clicked` for each bin?

Comment: To catch all values, you should also include the last bin: `x_axis_values = np.arange(1, 400+stepsize, stepsize)`. To create your plot, I would strongly recommend seaborn, e.g. `ax = sns.histplot(data=sample_df, x='sent_click_diff', hue='clicked_or_not', bins=x_axis_values, multiple='stack', stat='percent')`.

Comment: @JohanCThanks so much. It mostly does the job. Is there any way I can convert the bars into proportions? So each bar would be 100% and the hue would represent he proportion of `clicked_or_not` on a 100% scale.